Tuple Lock in Postgres
I've the following trigger where daily_shifts_tab and daily_shifts_wfv are identical tables and trigger is synchronising the data to daily_shifts_wfv from daily_shifts_tab.
The issue here is delete statements on daily_shifts_tab are causing tuple locks when the deletes are more frequent from the application. The delete statement from application is
delete from daily_shifts_tab where OBJECTID = $1;

id,objectid is PK on daily_shifts_tab and daily_shifts_wfv. This statement is causing the lock tuple. I don't understand why tuple lock is happening.
How to solve the issue?
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION daily_shifts_aiudr()
RETURNS trigger AS $body$
BEGIN
   if (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
       INSERT INTO daily_shifts_wfv (
           id,
           OBJECTID,
           PFID,
           INTIME,
           OUTTIME)
       VALUES(new.id,      
              new.OBJECTID,
              new.pfid,
              new.INTIME,   
              new.OUTTIME      
       ) ON CONFLICT (id,pfid,intime,scheduletype,schedtempassignoid) 
         DO NOTHING;
       RETURN NEW;
   elsif (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
       update daily_shifts_wfv 
          set pfid = new.pfid,
              intime = new.intime,
              outtime = new.outtime           
       where  id =  current_setting('ctx_ng_vpd.ctx_id_fil')
         and  OBJECTID = old.OBJECTID;               
       RETURN NEW;
   elsif (TG_OP = 'DELETE') then       
       delete from daily_shifts_wfv 
       where id =  current_setting('ctx_ng_vpd.ctx_id_fil') 
       and OBJECTID = old.OBJECTID;
       RETURN OLD;
   end if;        
END; $body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER daily_shifts_aiudr 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
  ON daily_shifts_tab 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE daily_shifts_aiudr();


A delete locks the deleted row. Any concurrent data modification on that row would be blocked+

My guess is you're having problems with the fact that a single operation with a large payload of N rows on daily_shifts_tab translates to N such operations on daily_shifts_wfv. Postgres does all the same stuff and locks all the same stuff on both tables, but it takes longer and locks hang longer on daily_shifts_wfv because of that. You could try to switch to a per-statement trigger that simply echoes the primary statement on your other table and see if that solves your problem.

As per the comment: my guess is you're having problems with the fact that a single operation with a large payload of N rows on daily_shifts_tab translates to N such operations on daily_shifts_wfv.
Postgres does all the same stuff and locks all the same stuff on both tables, but it takes longer and locks hang longer on daily_shifts_wfv because of the per-row split. You could try to switch your row-level trigger to a per-statement trigger that simply echoes the primary statement on your other table and see if that solves your problem.
Your schema and logic is a bit unclear:

You're not populating the scheduletype and schedtempassignoid columns so I'm guessing both tables have the same defaults on them
You seem to have an arbiter index on (id,pfid,intime,scheduletype,schedtempassignoid) apart from the PK you mentioned
Not sure what's the id in current_setting('ctx_ng_vpd.ctx_id_fil') doing but that looks like some sort of RLS attempt.

Disregarding or simplifying these away, here's an example:
demo at db<>fiddle
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION daily_shifts_aiudr()RETURNS trigger AS $body$
BEGIN  case TG_OP WHEN 'INSERT' then
           INSERT INTO daily_shifts_wfv (
               id,
               OBJECTID,
               PFID,
               INTIME,
               OUTTIME)
           SELECT newdata.id,      
                  newdata.OBJECTID,
                  newdata.pfid,
                  newdata.INTIME,   
                  newdata.OUTTIME      
           FROM newdata
           ON CONFLICT (id,pfid,intime,scheduletype,schedtempassignoid) 
           DO NOTHING;
       when 'UPDATE' then
           update daily_shifts_wfv as target
              set pfid = newdata.pfid,
                  intime = newdata.intime,
                  outtime = newdata.outtime           
           from newdata
           join olddata using(OBJECTID)
           where  target.id = olddata.id
             and  target.OBJECTID = olddata.OBJECTID;
       when 'DELETE' then       
           delete from daily_shifts_wfv as target
           using olddata
           where target.id = olddata.id
           and target.OBJECTID = olddata.OBJECTID;
       end case;        
       RETURN NULL;--doesn't matter in a statement-level trigger
END; $body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER daily_shifts_aiudr_insert
  AFTER INSERT
  ON daily_shifts_tab 
  REFERENCING NEW TABLE as newdata
  FOR EACH STATEMENT 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE daily_shifts_aiudr();

CREATE TRIGGER daily_shifts_aiudr_update
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON daily_shifts_tab 
  REFERENCING OLD TABLE as olddata NEW TABLE as newdata
  FOR EACH STATEMENT 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE daily_shifts_aiudr();

CREATE TRIGGER daily_shifts_aiudr_delete
  AFTER DELETE
  ON daily_shifts_tab 
  REFERENCING OLD TABLE as olddata
  FOR EACH STATEMENT 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE daily_shifts_aiudr();

You can see the operations on daily_shifts_tab get repeated on daily_shifts_wfv - the only difference is now it's the whole thing applied all at once instead of row-by-row.
insert into daily_shifts_tab
(id, OBJECTID, PFID, INTIME, OUTTIME,scheduletype,schedtempassignoid)values
 (2,2,1,now()-'1 min'::interval,now(),1,1)
,(3,3,1,now()-'1 min'::interval,now(),1,1)
,(4,4,1,now()-'1 min'::interval,now(),1,1);

select * from daily_shifts_wfv;




id
objectid
pfid
intime
outtime
scheduletype
schedtempassignoid




2
2
1
2024-12-13 09:39:24.253247+00
2024-12-13 09:40:24.253247+00
1
1


3
3
1
2024-12-13 09:39:24.253247+00
2024-12-13 09:40:24.253247+00
1
1


4
4
1
2024-12-13 09:39:24.253247+00
2024-12-13 09:40:24.253247+00
1
1



delete from daily_shifts_tab
where (id, OBJECTID)=(2,2);

select * from daily_shifts_wfv;




id
objectid
pfid
intime
outtime
scheduletype
schedtempassignoid




3
3
1
2024-12-13 09:39:24.253247+00
2024-12-13 09:40:24.253247+00
1
1


4
4
1
2024-12-13 09:39:24.253247+00
2024-12-13 09:40:24.253247+00
1
1



update daily_shifts_tab
set intime='infinity'
where (id, OBJECTID)=(3,3);

select * from daily_shifts_wfv;




id
objectid
pfid
intime
outtime
scheduletype
schedtempassignoid




4
4
1
2024-12-13 09:39:24.253247+00
2024-12-13 09:40:24.253247+00
1
1


3
3
1
infinity
2024-12-13 09:40:24.253247+00
1
1




Thanks you very much for the update! All your 1,2 and 3 points are correct. Yes,For every single operation on daily_shifts_tab, trigger fires and does same operation on daily_shifts_wfv table. So when a high number of delete operations occur in a given time(say 1 sec ~100's of deletes) on daily_shifts_tab table then the tuple locks happens. I will test your statement level trigger in load test and let you know

I don't see tuple locks with this approach . But it looks like the statement level trigger makes more sense when that delete statement deletes in batches instead of each objectid. For that app code changes would be required.
Thanks again for your help. @zegarek
